# How to identify REAL mouse movement when entering fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, fullscreen

I have the problem, that I need to know if the user actually moved his mouse for real when entering fullscreen, or if it just is a programatically side effect of entering the fullscreen.

Because, when entering fullscreen, the mouse Y coordinates change automatically because the mouse moves upwards on the absolute screen position (since the top navigation of the browser disappears). And since every browser brings a notification in fullscreen mode, this very notification triggers a mousemove event.

So, this makes it very painful to find out, whether the user acually move the mouse, or not.

**Is there a solution to identify REAL mouse movement?**

---

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
   /* gets also triggered when just entering fullscreen,
      but without actual movement of the physical mouse..
      how can this be identified/ignored?
   */
});
```

---

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/9aMSz/)

---

### What I've tried so far

I tried already relativating the mouse position by using something like `window.screen.top` - but this seems not to be implemented yet by any browser so far.

Comment: There's no way to do that, the mousemove event will be triggered when the user hits F11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now by saving the mouse coordinates, and check if they change - while I force one mousemove event after fullscreen in order to update the coordinates once.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    if(event.pageX == $(this).data('mouseX') && event.pageY == $(this).data('mouseY'))
         return;
    $(this)
        .data('mouseX',  event.pageX)
        .data('mouseY',  event.pageY)
    ;
});
$(document).mousemove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything formally implemented as yet to detect full screen. There's a `fullscreenchange` as part of the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) but it's still experimental and requires vendor-specific prefixes.

So, basically you'll have to get around that limitation with some tricks, like intersecting the `resize` event and skipping whatever logic you are running on `mousemove`. Here's an example...

```
var resizing = false;

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    if(resizing == false){
    $('p').text(event.pageX + ':' + event.pageY);
        console.log("moving");
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    resizing = true;

    setTimeout(function(){
        resizing = false;
    }, 4000);
});
```

This example simply defines a flag that determines whether the window is resizing or not, if resizing the `onmousemove` logic is skipped. Particularly I hate to use `setTimeout` with an arbitrary time to switch off the `resizing` flag, but if your requirements are not so strict it can get the job done beautifully

Comment: OK, I got the fullscreen part covered using a jQuery plugin. However, the delay is too long, since I hide navigation elements after 1 second, and the fullscreen message takes longer. So it appears, disappears, and appears and disappears again - which is disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you incorporate a delay (for example 0.5 seconds) where you ignore all mouse inputs. After the delay, any mouse movements are likely to be from the user...